# Node.js routes not working node.js + express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, fs

I had a node.js express server running on my server. I recently migrated to a new server and somehow the previous code has stopped to work.

Here is the setup of my server

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var https = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var util = require('util');
var url = require('url');
var HashMap = require('hashmap').HashMap;
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
var DBWrapper = require('node-dbi').DBWrapper; 
var DBExpr = require('node-dbi').DBExpr; 
var dbConnectionConfig = { host: 'localhost', user: 'mps', password: 'password', database: 'mps_schools' };
dbWrapper = new DBWrapper( "pg", dbConnectionConfig );
dbWrapper.connect();

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/', routes.index);
```

On this line the code is breaking

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

On logging "routes.index" to console, i get "undefined"

Here is the error log:

```
/home/mps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:291
throw new Error(msg);
      ^
Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
at /home/mps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:291:11
at Array.forEach (native)
at Router.route (/home/mps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:287:13)
at Router.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/mps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:318:16)
at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/mps/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:412:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mps/app22.js:62:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Impossible to say, but clearly the `routes` import is failing. Could be just about anything, but I'd make sure your environment is the "same", your build process is intact, etc.

Comment: Agree with @DaveNewton. Your import (require('./routes');) is failing. Post the code of routes.js and your project path structure. Otherwise it's hard to help more than that.

Comment: could it be because of version difference?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this may seem dumb but i didnt see it in the snippet. Are you sure you have added the 
'app.listen(PORT);'
Otherwise you could probably add your package config, there might be something there.
It's generally an environment change. What system were you on before, and what system are you hosting on currently.
Hope this gave a little clarity.

Comment: `listen` won't address the issue of the failing `require`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I changed the following to import

```
var routes = require('./routes');
```

to

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
```

and from the app.get i changed from

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

to

```
app.get('/', routes);
```